# Using curl, however my array will not post and content-type header does not send

Tags: php, xml, post, curl

Here's my code for performing the POST:

```
$url = "http://www.xxxxxxxxxxx.com/dfeed/index.cfm"; //where to send it
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1); // set url to post to
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); // set url to post to
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); // return into a variable
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: text/xml; charset=ISO-  8859-1'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 40); // times out after 4s
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data); // add POST fields
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
$result = curl_exec($ch); // run the whole process
echo $result;
//echo curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
curl_close ($ch);
```

My post array starts out with the same few (manually defined) entries like this:

```
$data[0] = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='ISO-8859-1'?>\n";
$data[1] = "<rss xmlns:g='http://base.google.com/ns/1.0' version='2.0'  xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'
```

xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation='http://www.xxxxx.com/dFeed/schemas/FeedSchema1.0.xsd'>\n";

The rest of them are populated in a loop like this:

```
array_push($data, "\t<item>\n");
```

The response from the server indicates a different content-type from what I have set, and also indicates it received no information so something must be wrong:

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request Transfer-Encoding: chunked Content-Type: text/htmlServer: Microsoft-IIS/7.0 X-XXX Server: Web2 Date: Mon, 25 Jun 2012 12:49:53 GMT Bad Request
Error: Not XML
Content received:
```

Comment: can you post $data like specify in this url and check once http://davidwalsh.name/execute-http-post-php-curl

Comment: Erm... why do you send an XML in chunks instead of sending it just in a single param? 400 Errors are usually caused by not following some rules set up by the URL's owner.

Answer (score 0):

The charset looks like it has whitespace in it or something, not sure if that was just on the way into SO or actually in your code.

Do you really need to add \t and \n around the place, the server won't care if you don't.

Try implode()ing the post array and just sending a string of XML.

No definitive answers but hopefully something in the right direction.

Let us know how you get on, good luck.